# How to keep content under a specific column in a table in react html

Tags: reactjs, html-table

I have a table that is filled dynamically as per this img[image]

There can be either 3 or 4 players per time. So if there are 4, another column is shown with `Player 4` and their details.

I want the two buttons `delete` `update` to always be under the admin column. If the times have different numbers of players i.e one has 3 and another has 4, in the row with 3 players, the two buttons appear under player 4 column.

Is it possible to keep them under the Admin column?

My table code is as follows

```
<Table striped bordered hover responsive>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th >Tee time</th>
            <th >Player 1</th>
            <th>Player 2</th>
            <th>Player 3</th>
            {props.teeTimes[0] !== undefined && props.teeTimes[0].noOfSlots === 4 &&
            <th>Player 4</th>}
            {props.loggedInUser.role === 'ADMIN' && !previous &&
            <th id='admin'>Admin</th>}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody >
        {props.teeTimes.map((teetime) => (
              <tr key={teetime.id}>
              <td>{teetime.teeTime}</td>
              {teetime.entrants.map((entrant) =>  (
                  <td 
                    key={entrant.member.id}>{entrant.member['firstName']} {entrant.member['surname']} ({entrant.member['handicap']})
                    <br></br>
                    <button 
                      className='btn btn-warning' onClick={() => removeTeeSheetEntrant(teetime.id, entrant.member.id)}>
                      Remove
                    </button>
                  </td>
                
              ))}
              
              {props.loggedInUser.role === 'ADMIN' && !previous &&
              <td headers='admin'>
                  <ButtonWithProgress className="btn btn-danger m-2" onClick={() => deleteTeeSheet(teetime.id)} text='Delete'/>
                  <button className="btn btn-warning m-2" disabled={true} onClick={() => handleShowEditTeeTime(teetime.id)}>Update</button>
              
              
              </td>}
              </tr>
        ))}   
        
        </tbody>
        
      </Table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that best solution is to print ever the player4 column, also if empty.

If you want to hide it if all rows has only player 3 you can check your data before render them and enable the fourth column only if you do not have any player4.
You can set a state like has4 to false, loop trough your data and set has4 to true on the first occurrence.